# With jQuery, how to automatically select the value of an input text that has been modified with the arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

I want to be able to increase/decrease the value of an input text with the keyboard arrows and have it automatically selected (with jQuery).

I succeed the increase/decrease part but I fail on the selection part.

I tried `$input.select();` with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".textInput").keydown(function(event) {
  var $input = $(this);

  if (event.which === 38) {
    $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) + 1));
  } else if (event.which === 40) {
    $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) - 1));
  }

  $input.select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="300" class="textInput">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/timmyyy/1L94j2ye/2/

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Relevant bullet in the latter: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Comment: you've done good by attempting the solution and having code to test - only it's not here, it's somewhere else. Please bring it here and create a snippet, then Im sure someone will give you a hand. Also, pls explain what 'fail on the selection part' means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be a conflict regarding jQuery resolving your `keydown` event and the call to `select()` on the same element being acted upon - the keydown callback needs to finish resolving before the `select()` is applied. This can be mitigated with a `setTimeout`

```js
$(".textInput").keydown(function(event) {
  let $input = $(this);
  if (event.which === 38)  $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) + 1));        
  else if (event.which === 40)  $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) - 1));
  setTimeout(() => $input.select());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="300" class="textInput">
```